# Unity2D How to make spikes spawn randomly and infinetly

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, infinite, auto-generate

I am making a infinite runner game for android and i want to make my spikes spawn randomly so every run is unique but i dont know how to do it i thought maybe i can use Invoke repeating and use random time to spawn them but that can mess them up Here is the following picture so you can get the whole idea

[image]

The bacground is looping backwards to make it look like the bunny is moving the only code i have for the spikes is a single line in the update

```
 transform.Translate (Vector3.left * SpikesSpeed);
```

Comment: What is your current solution?

Comment: @Hristo No solution i was thinking of using invoke repeating to spawn them randomly and like this way it will never be the same but it can mess them up for example if there are both spikes at top and bottom floor the bunny will die

Comment: I believe before addressing such a question you should ask yourself what are the exact constraints (maybe define a row/column situation, distance from each spike, etc...) Then the question is more concrete and specific.

Comment: I belive you can see the distance i want if you check out the picture no ?